# Alignment of Multiline textfield in within \item

Tags: hyperref, alignment, textfield

I would like to put a multiline Textfield in an enumerate einvironment. Unluckily the textfield is expanded to the top, not to the bottom of the page. The Numebr of the list is placed befor the last line of the texfield. Does anyone have any idea, how to prevent this?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,a4paper,DIV=9]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
text
\begin{enumerate}
\item Text
\item \TextField[width=6cm,multiline=true,name=Partei2]{}
\end{enumerate}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I use the `\belowbaseline` feature of `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,a4paper,DIV=9]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref,stackengine}
\begin{document}
text
\begin{enumerate}
\item Text
\item \belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{%
  \TextField[width=6cm,multiline=true,name=Partei2]{}}
\end{enumerate}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on *exactly* how you want the text aligned, you may have to account for the text-box padding (I used `\fboxsep` though perhaps that is not the precise value used by the text-box):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,a4paper,DIV=9]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref,stackengine}
\begin{document}
text
\begin{enumerate}
\item Text
\item \belowbaseline[\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox-\fboxsep-\fboxrule]{%
  \TextField[width=6cm,multiline=true,name=Partei2]{}}
\end{enumerate}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]