# pdflatex for pdf with interactive/fillable box with adjustable height to input

Tags: hyperref, pdf, input, textfield

Following up on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694633/fillable-text-form-with-auto-scalable-height) from August 2023, is there any update on creating a form on a hyperref generated pdf, with height adjustable (without rescaling) to the context, so it can be saved/printed? Scrolling only allows the visible area to be printed

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xparse,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref,stackengine}


\begin{document}

\item \belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{%
  \TextField[width=10cm,multiline=true,height=5cm, bordercolor=1 1 1, name=Stefanos]{}}
\vspace{6pt}

\end{document}
```

Copied pasted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451211/alignment-of-multiline-textfield-in-within-item)

I would be grateful for any hints

Comment: well I doubt that pdf allows that, but if you know an example of such a pdf (created with whatever tool)  I could tell you how to recreate that with latex.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer. We use them at work, and it is a hospital program, not sure what software is generated with. It is akin to Microsoft access but I do not think it is that. I just thought that it would be nice to have this functionality as the input text can vary from a few lines to a few paragraphs. When I find more about it I will amend the question.

Comment: well as I said if such a pdf one can reproduce it. Probably it uses some javascript, but without example it is hard to say and even harder to create directly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you!

Comment: If not possible to adjust the height is there a solution to printing the whole text and not only the visible region (assuming the input text is long enough to cause scrolling)?

Comment: How printing is done depends on the pdf viewer. That is not a LaTeX question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you again!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer one software, Morse from https://www.cambric.co.uk/products/morse, allows you to populate a fillable text field, When you save it, the text is then presented inside a different box with dimensions to fit the text length. It seems to be "extracted" if I am using the right word.

Comment: sorry but I will not install and run extensive tests in some external software to solve your problem. I don't have the time for this.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFisher. I did not for a moment thought that you would. I just followed on from previous discussion just to give an idea what I have in mind.  As you mentioned above, it probably uses some javascript. The whole discussion is very enlightening for me. My apologies if I have been inappropriate.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Hello! I have copied the "source" of such a document and truncated it to what I considered essential. It is still, however, 270 lines and I am not sure how I could upload it here.